# Better design to parse request/response in c++ socket client-server application

Tags: c++, design-patterns, command-pattern

I am developing a c++ client-server application using sockets. Client will send commands to server and server has to parse it and call appropriate module functions to process the request. At the client side, it has to parse the response and do some work based on that.

command format:

- **request**
  commandname-command1, modulename-module1, params-{param1,param2,...paramN)
- **response**
  commandname-command1, modulename-module1, status-success/failure,
  responsedata-data

Here I am writing parsing logic in both client and server to handle request/response commands. I found that parsing logic is almost similar in both client and sever. So I want to create some library to handle parsing and use that library in both client and server. Expecting better and well designed approach to handle this scenario. I am ready to change the command format if required.

Comment: What is the question? Better design for what?

Comment: And your question is? You can use Json and avoid writing your own parser

Comment: @geza better design for command parser.Each command a could be directed to any variety of software objects in my system.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear what you're asking. What is the current design of your command parser?

Comment: I like ZeroMQ for message-passing, and use some library for parsing the messages. Maybe protocol buffers? I would definitely recommend to read the ZeroMQ guide to anybody.